# Use "if" function to identify specific hours

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-formula

I have an excel table [see attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPhhh.png). I want to find which cells (rows) contain specific hours. To do so I used the if function:

```
=IF(B2=HOUR("12:00:00");"xx";"yes")
```

The outcome was not correct. As you can see the outcome was "yes" corresponding to false.. What is the problem ?

In addition, I tried to embed the "and" function, in order to select multiple hours, but the excel prompt error message. The formula I tried in cell B2 is:

```
=IF(B2=HOUR(AND("12:00:00";"3:00:00");"xx";"yes"))
```

error message:

> contain many conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have swapped the arguments in your comparison.
According to the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HOUR-function-A3AFA879-86CB-4339-B1B5-2DD2D7310AC7)

> [HOUR] returns the hour of a time value

If we evaluate your formula step by step, we get:

```
HOUR("12:00:00") -> 12
B2 = 12 -> false
IF(false; "xx"; "yes") -> yes
```

To fix this, change your condition to `HOUR(B2) = 12`.
That should work for a single hour.

If you want to check for multiple hour values, you can use the `OR` function, as noted in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51044414/9502074), but with modified conditions like this:

```
IF(OR(HOUR(B2) = 3; HOUR(B2) = 12); "xx"; "yes")
```

Comment: Deleted my answer - you beat me to it by a few seconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

First you just have misplaced the return of the true and the return of the false. Try :

```
=IF(B2=HOUR("12:00:00");"yes";"xx")
```

---

Second, you do not want a logical and but a logical or. And your condition is "if B2 is an hour that is equals to '12:00 and 3:00'" this has no sense. What you want is "if B2 is an hour that is equals to '12:00' or B2 is an hour that is equals to '3:00'". This should look like :

```
=IF(OR(B2=HOUR("12:00:00"), B2=HOUR("3:00:00")) ; "yes"; "xx"))
```

---

Edit : Thanks to [Korrat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045278/5914654) I can correct mine. The hour should not be compared like this. You should use the function `HOUR` on the cell and not on the value.

```
=IF(OR(HOUR(B2)=12, HOUR(B2)=3) ; "yes"; "xx"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it continues to show "xx" in all cells :(

Comment: @H.Johnson If it shows "xx" it means the logical test returned false

Comment: Yes but B6 has 12:00:00 hour , so it should return "yes" as an answer

Comment: @H.Johnson see my edit that correct the problem, thanks to [korrat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045278/5914654)